# How to memorize syntax of minimalist coding?

Tags: python

So I really like using Edabit to just practice coding, and it always comes at a surprise when I'm done with my answer, and I see other people's solution. They make my 10 line code into just a single line! I've heard of minimalist coding before, and have even tried to implement it, however, I just find it a lot more difficult to read and not what I'm used to seeing.

Everyone else makes it look so seamless, and easy, but when I try using it, I end up having to re-research the syntax and how it works.

**An example:**

My answer to a challenge:

```
def wumbo(words):
    print(words)
    words = list(words)
    print(words)
    count = -1
    for char in words:
        count+= 1
        if char == "M":
            words[count] = "W"
    print("".join(words))
    return "".join(words)
```

That's 11 lines of code! Even if you remove the `print` statements (They're for debugging), it's still a lot compared to other people's solutions.

These are examples of other people's:

```
def wumbo(words):
    return ''.join([i if i != 'M' else 'W' for i in words])
```

I think that^^ is an example of minimalistic coding?

And another example:

```
import re
wumbo=lambda w:re.sub('M','W',w)
```

I don't even know what "lamda" is!

So, are there any good resources in learning how to code really 'cleanly'? Or does it just take a lot of practice and memorization of syntax?

Comment: "Minimalist coding" might refer to something like [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf).

Comment: @AndersonGreen Thanks for the reference! Do you think that code golf/minimalistic code is more practical than just "regular" coding?

Comment: List comprehensions and lambdas are just features of the Python syntax.  You should learn how and where to use them just like you would any other part of Python.  List comprehensions certainly allow you to write more concise code.  I think often that's good, but I also think that there's a craze going on right now to do more and more in a single line of often nested list comprehensions that often goes too far in sacrificing readability for the goal of putting it all on one line...

Comment: ...Lambdas are a different thing.  They do save some typing, but that's not why you use them.  You use them to avoid defining a regular function when you will only need the function once, often when you want to pass code as a parameter.  But that's a special case.  In the usual case, where your first thought is to create a regular function, I don't think it's good style to do so with a lambda instead.  I don't see that being done in the wild, so it seems I'm in the majority in this belief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you need not worry about this.

1. Please understand coding for a code challenge and for collaborative project are different things. challenge need not be readable code as far as you are passing given test cases. where as if your code is becoming more readable at expense of 10 lines its acceptable. companies prefer it longer and readable code. as that code is maintained for long term and by many engineers.
   this doesn't give you permission to write optimized code.
2. Many programmers solve the problem by writing code and then try optimizing code. it comes by practice and consistent efforts. there is no blog or book which will teach you this overnight.
3. I think you are on right track.
   you wrote your code and looked for others implementations.
   do learn from there implementations.
   in given example lambda and regular expression was the things.
   lambda is new way of programming called functional programming.
   using which not just code become concise but it becomes faster too.
4. don't get overwhelmed by such things do read try to implement wherever possible and they will become part of your style.
5. do read documentation pages and try verifying things written in those docs.
6. keep asking question to your self once you verified your code is working.
   "can I optimist this further ?" "is there any better way to achieve this ?"
   try reading on internet about various ways of solving problem which you are trying to solve. try picking up whichever suits you.
7. get involved in opensource project try solving github issues.
   the maintainer will review your patch and provide you appropriate feedback.
8. opensource code is also considered as refined code as many developers keep resolving corner cases and improving code quality. reading such code also will give you better idea about how to code better in given language.
9. lastly try teaching others whatever you have learnt or explain your code to other programmers and get it reviewed. this helps you improve step by step.

Answer (score 2):

> So, are there any good resources in learning how to code really 'cleanly'? Or does it just take a lot of practice and memorization of syntax?

I'd say that clean and concise code comes with practice and experience. You will learn to recognise some patterns that can be minimised using different methods.
For instance:

- [List comprehensions](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) instead of `for` loops
- [Lambda functions](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/) instead of fully fletched functions
- [Regular expressions](https://realpython.com/regex-python/)
- High order functions like [map](https://realpython.com/python-map-function/)

and much more.

Comment: I would precise that comprehensions are really *Pythonic* because it is more efficient for example to build a list with a comprehension than by appending to an initially empty list. Lambdas are mainly syntactic sugar and are really useful when using callables having a function as parameter. For regular expressions they are very powerfull but have a hard syntax and should not be [abused](https://xkcd.com/1171/)

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Python, there is a philosophy of writing code

1. Beautiful is better than ugly.
2. Explicit is better than implicit.
3. Simple is better than complex.
4. Complex is better than complicated.
5. Flat is better than nested.
6. Sparse is better than dense.
7. Readability counts.
   These guides form the concept of Pythonic.

Although you may thing `minimalist coding` is fun and took less time to do, it is not always the best practice when it comes to code maintain and debug, as you often will spend more time understanding the code rather than actually coding it.

If you must chase this path, I suggest that you really dig deeper into the different syntax and code structure to Python first, such as constructing a list from a loop or list comprehension already make a lot of difference. The core of `minimalist coding` is how well you understand your own algorithm and how to achieve the same goal by reducing the steps/code.

Reference: [Pythonic](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/p/pythonic.htm)